# ALLOWED_HOSTS['*'] - TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: django

I'm setting up a Django project right now based on the Django Girl's tutorial and my settings.py file keeps throwing the following error:

```
File "/Users/me/Documents/programming/django_girls_tut/djangogirls/settings.py"", line 116, in <module>
ALLOWED_HOSTS['*']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

When I comment out the ALLOWED_HOSTS, it runs without a hitch.
Here's the rest of my settings file:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
import dj_database_url

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'keeeeey'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djangogirls.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djangogirls.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = False

DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
SECURE_PROXY_SLL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

# BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print('BASE_DIR2 = ' + BASE_DIR)
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass

ALLOWED_HOSTS['*']
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

need to assign the array, forgot the =

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Comment: @DigitalMockingbird, Mark as answer, if this solves your problem, this will help people with same issue.